# How to resize an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, resize, image-resizing

I am using a switch statement and a random, rounded number to load a randomised picture of a cat in my application. But I can't seem to resize it. At the moment it just covers the entire screen. I am relatively new to Javascript so I haven't found a way to do this yet.

I have tried to create a new function etc. but I would much rather if there was something I could put in the switch statement or CSS.

```
function randomCat() {
let number = Math.floor(Math.random()* 20);

switch(number) {
case 0:
document.body.style.image = 'url("cat1.jpg")';
break;
case 1:
document.body.style.image = 'url("cat2.jpg")';
break;
case 2:
document.body.style.image = 'url("cat3.jpg")';
break;
case 3:
document.body.style.image = 'url("cat4.jpg")';
break;
case 4:
document.body.style.image = 'url("cat5.jpg")';
break;
case 5:
document.body.style.image = 'url("cat6.jpg")';
break;
```

There is a background image behind the cat pictures and I would like the pictures to be small so that the background image shows up behind it.

Comment: You're assigning the random image as background-image for `body`. Just use a div instead. Also: `document.body.style.image = 'url(cat' + (number + 1) + '.jpg)';`

Comment: sorry, I'm not great at JavaScript could you please write me an example

Answer (score 0):

`style` attribute do not have `image` property. If you want to add the `background-image`,  use `backgroundImage`. You are attaching the images to the `body` of document. Instead your can create a container like `div` and set `height` and `width` to div, then you can attach the images to this div.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

function randomCat() {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random()* 20);
    console.log(number);
    switch(number) {
    case 0:
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://htmlreference.io/images/traffic.jpg")';
    break;
    case 1:
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://www.html-5-tutorial.com/images/atitlan.jpg")';
    break;
    case 2:
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("cat3.jpg")';
    break;
    case 3:
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("cat4.jpg")';
    break;
    case 4:
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("cat5.jpg")';
    break;
    case 5:
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("cat6.jpg")';
    break;
    default: 
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://www.html-5-tutorial.com/images/atitlan.jpg")';
    break;
    }
}

randomCat();
```

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
body {
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```